# HTML Source Code get element between two html tags that are commented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to check with javascript if between two html tags that are commmented, exist a div? See the example below:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>.....</div>
    <h1>.....</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- #html# -->
          Get these Value
          <!-- #/html# -->
          <td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- #html# -->
          ....
    <!-- #/html# -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? I'm trying to figure out why you would comment out your `<html>` tags.

Comment: I made a mistake with the example yesterday. They aren´t tags, but they are nested with the hashtag (#), see example above. These comments are made by the newsletter system. And if these comments have a div-tag inside, it means that the user can edit it on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ES6, but you can achive it by classic iteration over `childNodes`.

```js
var res = [], isInside = false;

for (var node of document.body.childNodes) {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
    if (node.nodeValue.trim() === "<html>") {
      isInside = true;
      continue;
    } else if (node.nodeValue.trim() === "</html>") {
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (isInside) { // No else - include other comments
    res.push(node);
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

```html
<!-- <html> -->
    <div>...</div>
<!-- </html> -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, thats the solution that i searched. With some modifying I can use it for my own code.

Comment: I have a problem now. This method works great if the elements are on the first level of the document body, but if they are nested into other tags I can´t get these comments. (ps: they comments have now the value #html#    See example above...)

Comment: @Perhp, use recursive dom traversal.

Comment: Do you mean like this?

`function walkTheDOM(node, func) {

    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    var res = []
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

walkTheDOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
     var isInside = false;
        if (node.nodeValue.trim() === "#html#" && node.nextSibling.nextSibling.nodeName === 'DIV') {
     isInside = true;
            console.log(node)
        } 
    }
});`

Comment: @Perhp, smth like that, but your version seems strange.

Comment: How whould you do that if you have to check the element tag inside the comment??

Comment: @Perhp, what do you mean by "inside"?

Comment: with "inside" i mean how do you can check if inside the comment-tag exist a div tag like this: <!--#html#--><div>...</div><!--#/html#-->

Comment: @Perhp, seems like I answered this question. If not, clarify the problem.